# I want to Collapse a VSCode tree view programatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is there any way to collapse the tree view programatically.

I want to collapse my tree view when a button is clicked

PFA Screenshot.

[image]

I want Minimise the Firmware Layout View when 'Locate in Project View' is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

There is a commit with a new command which may help, see [157410 Add Command to Fully Collapse Tree Items](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/3ba86a3c9f8ac5d02779c60cf6abe06c6a2ebdda) and in that commit this command:

```
list.collapseAllToFocus
```

[Update: now that I can test this I don't think this new command does what you need - it doesn't get to the top of the view and collapse that.  It does collapse any included item and any of its included subItem items (so collapsing recursively - which is new) - but not at the top level, which is what you need.]

---

Here is an issue on this: [API to programatically expand/collapse tree view](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88219)

You can collapse that view - its contents only - but it appears you can't actually close the view itself - so it is reduced to a single line. Which I think is what you want.  To collapse the contents so they are not visible (but still taking up their previous vertical space) read on.  If there were a way to focus that `view header` which I believe it is called, then it would be easy to collapse the entire thing with the `list.collapse` command.

---

If you have your extension running, either in the Extension Host for testing or an installed version, look in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` and type `collapse`.  You will see that vscode automatically creates a command like this:

`workbench.actions.treeView.*******.collapseAll` with your treeView `id` where the asterisks are.

So you could call that command the usual way with:

`vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.actions.treeView.IDHere.collapseAll');`

---

By the way, vscode also creates a

`workbench.actions.treeView.someTreeViewIDHere.refresh` command for all custom TreeViews.

Comment: `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.actions.treeView.IDHere.collapseAll');` did the trick.

Comment: I also tried `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.actions.treeView.IDHere.expandAll');` but that is not a valid command.

Comment: Yes, there is no `expand all` treeview command.