# How to change visibility of views in the sidebar via the VSCode-Extensions API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: clicking the caret for visibility change]

You can change the visibility by clicking the caret seen in the screenshot above. Is there a way to trigger this visibility change via the API? I can't find any setter for the visibility inside the VSCode Extension API-documentation

In this case this is a `TreeView` and this means the needed method would trigger the views `onDidChangeVisibility`-Event.

Comment: if you use a user defined context variable in the `when` clause of the view you can control the visibility

Comment: When you say "visibility", do you mean collapse/expand or get rid of that view altogether?

Comment: actually either would be fine.
but what you proposed is very good, i actually need to know the status of the visibility, which is why i go with @rioV8 suggestion and utilize `setContext`. Your suggestions work fine as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to collapse the view (and not just its contents), I think the answer is that it cannot be done programmatically from an extension at this point.

See [API to programatically expand/collapse tree view](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88219): which is "On Deck" (and I think could be easily implemented - so upvote it).

If you were happy to just collapse the contents of the view but not the entire view, see [I want to Collapse a VSCode tree view programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72174813/836330).

Finally, it is relatively easy to remove the view altogether, see [how to use vscode extension to hide timeline and outline in the side bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324633/836330) and

`await vscode.commands.executeCommand('timeline.removeView');`

but I can't find a good way to programmatically add a view back except

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.quickOpen', 'view NPM Scripts');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem');
```

which is less than optimal.  If, however, it is your treeView you could use the `TreeView.reveal()` command which will open the view if it is closed.  You do have to pass some element to the `reveal()`, perhaps the root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I found the other command that will reveal a view:

```js
 vscode.commands.executeCommand(`[YOUR_VIEW_ID_HERE].focus`);
```

To find other commands open command palette and find Keyboard shortcuts, and then type view id:
[image]